# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression in to data type datetime

Tags: sql-server, math, datetime

Hoping someone can help. I've looked on the internet for a solution but none seem to resolve it.

I want to query a large table and only get the results back where a column equals today's date.

Here's the query:

```
select [Table1].[Field1]
from [Table1]
where [Table1].[Field1] = GetDate()
```

The date format is as follows:

```
 20020630
```

I'm a beginner in SQL so any help would be really appreciated because I am growing fond of it.

Thank you!!! :)

Comment: What datatype is field1?

Comment: Im not sure becasue the table is on a linked server and i dont have full access to it, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

To find the broken value:

```
select [Table1].[Field1]
from [Table1]
where ISDATE([Table1].[Field1]) = 0
```

GETDATE includes a time, so you need to remove this. This assumes SQL Server 2008+

```
select [Table1].[Field1]
from [Table1]
where [Table1].[Field1] = CAST(GetDate() AS date)
```

Comment: Its SQL Server 2008 R2. Ive just tried the GetDate solution and that says the following:

Comment: Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type date is not a defined system type.

Comment: And the first solution (ISDATE) doesnt return any values.

Comment: @PDB: date is a valid type in SQL Server 2008+. Your linked server must be SQL Server 2005 or earlier and this code is executing there. You need to know datatype for Field1.

Comment: Is there any way to find tht out by using a query?

Comment: @PDB: hard to say. don't have enough information if a cast to date fails. It would mean running stuff remotely. If you don't know datatype, you won't have rights to find out more.

Comment: Okay thanks alot. Do suppose you'd know how to check a list of ids and the select then select the latests ones from another table and insert them would you??